# Error: Bad state: Future already completed

Tags: flutter, dio

[image]

I tried to call api using dio then I met this error.

`  Future _getHomeData() async {
try {
var homeDataResponse = await HomeService().getHomeData();

```
  final classList = (homeDataResponse.data['classes']) as List;
  classes = classList.map((i) => ClassModel.fromJson(i)).toList();
  _storageService
      .writeSecureData(StorageItem("user_classes", jsonEncode(classes)));

  final examList = (homeDataResponse.data['exams']) as List;
  exams = examList.map((i) => Exam.fromJson(i)).toList();
  _storageService
      .writeSecureData(StorageItem("user_exams", jsonEncode(exams)));

  final taskList = (homeDataResponse.data['tasks']) as List;
  tasks = taskList.map((i) => Task.fromJson(i)).toList();
  _storageService
      .writeSecureData(StorageItem("user_tasks", jsonEncode(exams)));

  // for (var subject in subjects) {
  //   print("SUBJECtS ${subject.subjectName}");
  // }
} catch (error) {
  if (error is DioError) {
    throw Result.error(error.response?.data['message']);
  } else {
    throw Result.error(error.toString());
  }
}
```

}
`

Comment: Which dio version are you using?

Comment: I used dio: ^4.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wrote as a comment that you use version 4.0.6, I can inform you that version had a known issue. It is solved in a later version, so update to at least 5.0 of dio and all will be good.

You can read about the issue [here](https://github.com/cfug/dio/issues/1480) and read about it's fix [here](https://github.com/cfug/dio/pull/1550).